# Heroku deployment ValueError when installing dependencies with Pip

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am trying to deploy a Django 1.7 project to a new app in Heroku but I get the following ValueError on the Django requirement.

```
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'Django==git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b4', 'at', '+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b4')
```

My requirements.txt snippet is:

```
Django==git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct format for a git URL in a pip requirements file.

You should use this:

```
git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b4#egg=Django
```

See the [pip documentation](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files).